# Django ignores 404.html

Tags: python, html, django

I wrote a custom `404.html` for my Django application and put it in the templates directory (same place as `index.html`), but Django still displays the default 404 page. `Debug` is set to `false` and `allowed hosts` is set to `127.0.0.1` (for testing purposes, it will be changed later). How is that possible, I thought creating a `404.html` should be enough? Do I somehow need to activate the error page in some setting?

here is my app structure:

```
myapp
|-- manage.py
|-- myapp
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- templates
|   |   |-- index.html
|   |   |-- 404.html
```

Comment: Where have you placed `404.html`? Please show the directory structure.

Comment: Your structure isn't optimal. `settings.py` and `models.py` shouldn't be together. The directory templates should be at top level in your project. Did you really try the structure proposed in my answer? What do you get when you call a non-existing URL? If you run your app with `python manage.py runserver` what do you see in the console output? Is there http status code 404?

Comment: Set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` for testing purposes. In production you'll change it. Then try again.

Comment: Putting the template directory with the 404.html at top level and changing the allowed hosts didn't change anything. Yes, the HTTP 404 is raised but it shows the default 404 template. The console output is [22/Oct/2014 15:08:19] "GET /blabla/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2687

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by configuring the template dirs:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`404.html` should be placed directly in the directory `templates`.

For example something like this:

```
yourproject
|-- manage.py
|-- yourproject
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
|-- yourapp
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- static
|-- templates
|   |-- 404.html
|   |-- yourapp
`   `-- anotherapp
```

You should NOT put it together with the templates of your app (like index.html).

Comment: I tried this structure as well but it had no effect. Something is still missing. Do I need to overwrite some settings? (I ask because the answer that suggests that is voted down.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the default view handler for the 404 error.
Django documentation provide answer for your question:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404